# AS3 Variable trouble

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I have some code that is similar to this and its not working.

```
var sensor:Number;
var toucher:Number;


fixtureB.GetBody().SetUserData("sensortouched-0";
var sensorArray:Array = fixtureB.GetUserData().split("-", 2);
sensor=sensorArray[1];


fixtureA.GetBody().SetUserData("sensortouched-0";
var sensorArray:Array = fixtureA.GetUserData().split("-", 2);
toucher=sensorArray[1];

if (toucher==0 && sensor==0)
{
trace("test");
}
```

tracing sensor or toucher does equal "0" but it doesn't seem to enter the if statement ?

Thanks

Comment: fixtureB.GetBody().SetUserData("sensortouched-0");

Comment: sensor or toucher does equal "0" or sensor and toucher does equal "0"

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your problem, or leave a comment to let me know what else you have a problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't enter the `if` statement, because you try to compare a string and a number. `Split` function returns an array of strings. You should compare like this:

```
if (toucher == "0" && sensor == "0")
{
   trace("test");
}
```

I don't even know how do you assign a `String` to a `Number`. That's some bad practice over there. I'd suggest reading more about [Casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

And BTW, you should assign it like this:

```
sensor = parseInt(sensorArray[1]);
```